# How to change text inside ipynb file with python programmatically

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have password as variable inside my `ipynb` file.

How with help of python I can programmatically change this password for new one?

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
with open("file.ipynb", "r") as initial_file:
    text = initial_file.read()
    text.replace('passwordone', 'passwordtwo')
with open("file.ipynb", "w") as new_file:
    new_file.write(text)
```

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I don't want to do it manually. I want to automate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the text variable to the new value

```
with open("file.ipynb", "r") as initial_file:
    text = initial_file.read()
    text = text.replace('passwordone', 'passwordtwo')

with open("file.ipynb", "w") as new_file:
        new_file.write(text)
```

Comment: thank you! after 8 minutes I will be able to accept your answer :D

Comment: I'm taking out the "open two files at the same time" bit of the answer, because you want to use the same file to write to that you opened earlier.